# Does Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) work with Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

C2DM required a Google ID, and now C2DM has been replaced by GCM which apparently does not require a Google ID.

Does this mean it is simply compatible with devices (such as the Kindle Fire) that does not have Google Play Appstore or the Google stack available to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The mechanism that actually receives the messages from GCM server relies on the Google Services Framework, the bundled services such as Google Play and GTalk are part of the framework.

If you don't have the framework installed you cannot receive messages from the GCM server. Basically it won't work if you don't have the Google Services Stack on your phone.

Refer to this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html

> It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the
>   Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running
>   Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to
>   deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store.

Answer (score 3):

Kindle for tablet support ADM (Amazon device messaging) it's similar like GCM, but difference in implementation. [Find here more about ADM](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm.html)

Answer (score 1):

where have you read that it does not require a google id? It seems to me like it still requires a google account?

Snipped from the documentation:

```
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Based on http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-send-push-notifications-to-Android-without-using-a-Google-ID-on-the-device apparently doesn't require Google ID.

Comment: maybe the guys in google made a mistake in the documentation then. even-though they do state in quite clear terms that it does require a google account.

Comment: The GET_ACCOUNTS permission is not required for Android 4.0.4+.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. I think Google Cloud Messaging requires Google Play Services to be on the device.